# How do I get a function to run with the .onsubmit event?

Tags: javascript, html

There is probably a really easy solution to this but I cannot for the life of me work out how to fix this issue, and nothing I have found so far has done the trick.

I'm trying to get the function "validate" to run when the form "apply" is submitted:

```
function init() {
  var applyForm = document.getElementById("apply");
  setJobValue();
  applyForm.onsubmit = validate;
}
```

Validate looks like the following:

```
function validate() {
  alert("If this alert is up then validate is running");
  var dateOfBirth = document.getElementById("dob").value;
  var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
  var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
```

etc.

The function "setJobValue" is running (so I know init is working) and there are no errors in the console, but what adjustments would I have to make for validate to be called?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the submit button does work (in that it bounces back the values to the user as it should), it just doesn't seem to run "validate" first

Comment: Do you find any error in console ?

Comment: Nah, no errors in the console

Comment: Is `apply` id of the `form` element ?

Comment: Can you share your markup ?

Comment: Working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/zqdhus49/

Comment: Try moving all script blocks at the end of page after html

Comment: @Pixel I've got it as a separate file (referenced in the head by a script tag)

Comment: @ChoiceKarpz, Do share a fiddle.. I can not access `pastebin`..

Comment: Put your code at the end then it should work just fine.

Comment: @Rayon https://jsfiddle.net/j826zudx/

Comment: `alert = alert + "` ? NO, you should not do that...

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/j826zudx/1/ Add `novalidate` attribute in `form` tag and DO NOT use `alert` as a variable..

Comment: @Rayon Thanks man. Issue was the alert variable. Changed it to "msg" in mine (as you had on jsfiddle) and now it works as it should. Thanks heaps :)

Comment: @ChoiceKarpz, I'm glad to help you man!

Answer (score 0):

Well, what happens is that when you put your code above in the head, the script runs when the HTML gets rendered. So during that time, it allocates different memory and function blocks. So when you call that function again, then it gives you different results and no errors because of the existing references. Well its a bit weird but its the way JS works and it is always recommended to put your JS code at the bottom of the page.

Comment: then fiddle please :)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call validate method from your init method instead.

```
function init() {
  var applyForm = document.getElementById("apply");
  setJobValue();
  validate();
}
```

Comment: Why would he want to validate on init? Init is most probably the first thing that happens, before a user interacts with the page.

Answer (score 0):

When we assign a function to an event, it will fire at last.
so in your case, This should work

```
    function init() {
            var applyForm = document.getElementById("apply");
            setJobValue();
            applyForm.onsubmit = functionToSave;
        }
```

And call your validation method on the submit button onclick event.